# How to create a string-type variable in C

Tags: c, string, variable-declaration

**Question**

How to declare a string variable in C?

**Background**

In my quest to learn the basics of [c](/questions/tagged/c), I am trying to port one of my oldest [python](/questions/tagged/python) programs, `Bob`, to C. In the program, the script asks the user for information on him or herself, and then spits out responses. Almost all of these variables use `raw_input` for their information - the variables are strings. But, I have found no way to declare C variables.

**Code**

So far, I have tried to declare the variable as of type `char` and `int.` Here is the code, switch the type at your leisure.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int name;
    printf("What is your name?");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("Your name is %s", name );

    return 0;
}
```

**Error Message**

When I run this code, `Xcode` returns some weird stuff. This part of the globidty-gloop is highlighted.

```
0x7fff96d2b4f0:  pcmpeqb(%rdi), %xmm0
```

Lasty, [this Yahoo Answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080715104545AA4uejN) said that I had to use something called a `character array`. It was posted 5 years ago, so I assumed that there was a better way.

**EDIT**

I am following the tutorial at [C Programming](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html).

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:python]?

Comment: A string is a 0-terminated character array. Still.

Comment: Why are you using an integer for `name`?

Comment: Also, this is a C tutorial level question. I suggest following one. (The pedantic but useless answer is that C doesn't have a string type, only character arrays, and string manipulation functions that expect them to be null-terminated.)

Comment: @millimoose: Probably because "I am trying to port one of my oldest python programs...".

Comment: @FredLarson Ah. Seems like a silly reason then.

Comment: There is no better way since the Yahoo answer was posted. The answer there is still the best one.

Comment: Try reading a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/10077).

Comment: Use a linked list of char's. Having a small block of char's would be more efficient than a single char. Something like 5, 10 or 20 byte chunks depending on the implementation. In the long run it is much better to learn how to use char arrays though.

Comment: "It was posted 5 years ago, so I assumed that there was a better way."

lol

Answer (score 10):

```
char name[60];
scanf("%s", name);
```

Edit: restricted input length to 59 characters (plus terminating 0):

```
char name[60];
scanf("%59s", name);
```

Comment: Surely you mean `scanf("%59s", name)` ?

Comment: @cnicutar yes, but that is a subject of buffer overflow question :)

Comment: Well since you're dealing with a self-proclaimed beginner there's no point in teaching questionable habits from the start.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk so... what happens if my name is over 60 characters?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx Undefined behavior. Most likely input will write all over the stack.

Comment: Also, the `scanf` is in yellow in xcode. It says `Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char(*)[60]'`

Comment: @xxmbabanexx As this variable is automatic, you will get SIGSEGV when trying to return from function. As `printf` uses buffered output, you will likely not see the message. And consider yourself lucky if you program just crashes quick and dirty: it is easy to catch and fix. Otherwise you will get a headache with your program behaving in some strange manner

Answer (score 3):

The int your putting is not a string, a string looks like "char myString[20]".
Not like "int name", that's an integer and not a string or char. This is the code you want:

```
         int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

char name[9999];
printf("What is your name?\n");
scanf("%s", name);
system("cls");
printf("Your name is %s", name);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C you can not direct declare a string variable like Java and other language. you'll have to use character array or pointer for declaring strings.

```
char a[50];
printf("Enter your string");
gets(a);
```

OR

```
char *a;
printf("Enter your string here");
gets(a);
```

OR

```
char a[60];
scanf("%59s",a);
```

Comment: Is better don't use gets, use fgets as I did in my answer. Why? I had several problems with a more complex problem using gets

Answer (score 1):

***TESTED ON XCODE***

You can do so:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int i;
    char name[60]; //array, every cell contains a character

    //But here initialize your array

    printf("What is your name?\n");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    printf("Your name is %s", name );

    return 0;
}
```

Initialize the array, is good to avoid bug

```
for(i=0;i<60;i++){
      name[i]='\0'; //null
}
```

Instead `int` is used for int number (1, 2, 3, ecc.); For floating point number instead you have to use `float`

Comment: What does `fgets` and the related arguments mean?

Comment: 'fgets' put character by character in every cell for the lenght of the array name and put after the last cell used '\0' that means null. stdin clean the stream of the input

Answer (score 0):

C does not have a string variable type. Strings can be stored as **character arrays** (char variable type). The most basic example I would add up to the rest is:

```
int main()
{
   char name[] = "Hello World!";
   printf("%s",name);
   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## It's easy!

Just put this line below, atop of your `main()` function.

```c
typedef string char*;
```

This allows you to create a string variable as you do with *integers* or *characters* in C. After that, your program should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char* string;

int main(void) {
    string a = "Hello";
    printf("%s\n", a);  // %s format specifier for String
    return 0;
}
```

For a **live demonstration**, visit [this REPL.it](https://repl.it/@AbhigyanKumar/ModernBlindShareware).

Comment: You typed the type declaration backward when you say, "just put this line...". Then, in the block below, you have it right.

Answer (score -1):

Normally we use "&" in scanf but you shouldn't use it before variable "name" here. Because "name" is a char array. When the name of a char array is used without "[]", it means the address of the array.

Answer (score -2):

replace int name; to--. char name[60];

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char name[648];
  printf("What is your name?");

  scanf("%s", name);
  printf("Your name is %s", name );

  return 0;
}
```