# Why is the else statement not being executed while using scanf() and printf()?

Tags: c

```
    int p;
    int j;
    printf("Who is Palpatine?\n");
    scanf("%s", &j);
    if (j = "Senate") 
        {
        printf("Your number sir?\n");
        scanf("%d", &p);
        printf("CT %d, the time has come. Execute Order Sixty-Six.\n", p);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("Incorrect\n");
        }
     return 0;


}
```

I have been testing these lines of code and right now if I write anything in the prompt, it goes through the section where if I said Senate, even if I did not type Senate, and skips my else statement. The example in executed code picture is when I typed in Sen instead of Senate.

Also crossed out sections of the code in the executed code picture do not deal with the question, and my spacing is atrocious.

Thanks and all feedback is appreciated.

[Executed Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPWyt.png)

[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7l99.png)

Comment: `if (j = "Senate")` is wrong in so many ways.  First, you declared `j` to be an `int`, not a string.  Second, you are making an _assignment_, not an equality check.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the actual code as text, not as a screen capture.

Comment: Did you ignore compiler warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare j as a string to hold the senate, then in your scanf(), only do "j", not &j, since it is a string. Also, do if j == the Senate, rather than j = the senate. One = is assignment but two is checking equality.

Hope this helps!

edit: use strcmp(j, "the Senate")

Comment: Use `strcmp` for string.

Comment: Should be `if(strcmp(j, "Senate")==0){`

Comment: Thanks, I will test this out when I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you noticed in your code, you `scanf` statement is wrong.
This is your `scanf` statement:

```
scanf("%s", &j);
```

If you noticed you are using `%s` in the statement with `&j`. Earlier in the code, you stated that `j` is an integer. Therefore, you should be using `%d`. To fix your code, make your `j` into a string to store letters. To do this, click this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420696/how-to-create-a-string-type-variable-in-c) and it will take you to a StackOverflow question on to create a string-type variable.

Also, in you `if` statement change: `if (j = "Senate")` to if `(j = 'Senate')`. You WILL get an error when if you do it with `""`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer while I did look at the link and it helped I did     if(j == 'Senate'), to show for equality, I did char j[7]; and scanf("%6s", j); but I get the error "too many characters in an characters constant."

Comment: You are getting that error because it contains way too many letters in it. It has to contain one character for some reason. You could look up your problem online for a solution.